# Data Migration to sharepoint

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have the below two functionality to be achieved.

```
 1. Migrating data from MS SQL Server to share point.
 2. Migrating data from file (text,excel,csv) to share point.
```

What will be the best way to do this ?

Comment: This may be of interest to you:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2763/using-ssis-to-automatically-populate-a-sharepoint-list/   it's going to require installing some 3rd party open source software